# DuetHeuristic-BM and nsurlsessiond hogging CPU and Memory on MacBook Air

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, cpu

I recently updated my MacBook Air to macOS 10.12.2 and there are these two programs, **DuetHeuristic-BM and nsurlsessiond** which have been hogging CPU and memory continuously:

[image]

This heats up the machine and has significantly reduced the battery life. I went through the logs in Console and the most common logs that I see for these processes are as follows:-

**DuetHeuristic-BM**

> :[
>     ] sumScores:38.410000, denominator:42.410000, FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed FinalScore: 0.000000}

and **nsurlsessiond**

> HTTP load failed (error code: -1001 [4:-2104])
>   NSURLSessionTask finished with error - code: -1001
>   Task 281 for client  will be retried after error - code: -1001

etc.

I am not sure what's causing this. My MacBook is critical to my work and this issue is causing me a lot of trouble. This has been happening the whole day, please help.

**Update**

Had a call with the Apple Customer support regarding this, they suggested me to reformat the MacBook and it worked. The processes aren't showing up at all, the laptop is working perfectly.

Comment: Have you restarted your Mac?

Comment: Many times. The issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

This link

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7810604

explains that *nsurlsessiond* manages network connections and *DuetHeuristic-BM* is a process started by Duet Activity Scheduler (DAS). This may be a child process of Grand Central Dispatch (GCD).

Its function appears to be to assign weights in order to make decisions about things like when Time Machine will backup or Spotlight will start indexing.

Perhaps the DuetHeuristic is stuck on a file on your computer and is stuck in an endless loop.